# Problems with dynamic RegExp construction in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, user-input

This method is to prevent users from entering anything but numbers and "allowed characters."  Allowed characters are passed as the parameter `allowedchars`.

So far, the method prevents number entries but the allowedchars doesn't work (tried with passing "-" (hyphen) and "." (period)).  So I'm assuming my dynamic regex construction isn't correct.  Help?

Thanks in advance!

```
numValidate : function (evt, allowedchars) {
    var theEvent, key, regex,
    addToRegex = allowedchars;

    theEvent = evt || window.event;
    key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
        key = String.fromCharCode(key);
        var regex = new RegExp('/^[0-9' + addToRegex + ']$/');
        if (!regex.test(key)) {
            theEvent.returnValue = false;
            if (theEvent.preventDefault) {
                theEvent.preventDefault();
            }
        }
}
```

(ps. jQuery solutions are fine too)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.** When you construct via `new RegExp`, there's no need to include the surrounding `/`s.

```
    var regex = new RegExp('^[0-9' + addToRegex + ']$');
```

**2.** But if `addToRegex` contains `]` or `-`, the resulting regex may become invalid or match too much. So you need to escape them:

```
    var regex = new RegExp('^[0-9' + addToRegex.replace(/([\-\]])/g, '\\$1') + ']$');
```

**3.** But since you are checking against 1 character anyway, it may be easier to *avoid* regex.

```
    var pass = ("0123456789" + addToRegex).indexOf(key);
    if (pass == -1) {
      ...
```

Comment: Sorry @KennyTM...you are totally right.  I thought I had copied and pasted it but chopped out a bracket from the middle, mid-ether. :) I've deleted my prior comment.  Thanks for the answer!